# Numpy array in panda dataframe from json

Tags: python, json, pandas, numpy

I have a JSON file containing properties of some mathematical objects (Calabi-Yau manifolds). These objects are defined by a matrix and a vector, and two additional properties I am storing are the matrix size (such that it does not need to be computed again) and the Euler number of the manifold (some integer). In total there are roughly 1 million entries, the biggest matrix is 16 x 20.

I would like to convert the matrix and vectors to numpy arrays. Hence I was wondering if it is possible to do it directly when loading from json, or at least how to convert afterwards. The reason for converting is that I will need in any case some functions from numpy later, but I also hope (especially if the conversion is done on loading) that it will speed up my code: for the moment loading the complete dataset takes roughly 90 seconds (a previous loading using json module required only 20 s; I will open another thread on this question if using numpy does not improve).

Here is a minimal working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

json = '''
{"1":{"euler":2610,"matrix":[[6]],"size":[1,1],"vec":[5]},
"2":{"euler":2190,"matrix":[[2,5]],"size":[1,2],"vec":[6]},
"4":{"euler":1632,"matrix":[[2,2,4]],"size":[1,3],"vec":[7]},
"6":{"euler":1152,"matrix":[[2,2,2,3]],"size":[1,4],"vec":[8]},
"7":{"euler":960,"matrix":[[2,2,2,2,2]],"size":[1,5],"vec":[9]},
"8":{"euler":2160,"matrix":[[2],[5]],"size":[2,1],"vec":[1,4]},
"9":{"euler":1836,"matrix":[[0,2],[2,4]],"size":[2,2],"vec":[1,5]}}
'''

data = pd.read_json(json, orient="index")
data.sort_index(inplace=True)
```

My first guess was to use the `numpy` argument, but it fails with an error:

```
>>> data = pd.read_json(json, orient="index", numpy=True)
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 51 into shape (7,4,2,2)
```

Then I have tried giving the `dtype` argument but it does not look like changing anything (my hope was that by using a numpy type it would convert the list to an array):

```
>>> dtype = {"euler": np.int16, "matrix": np.int8, "vector": np.int8,
...          "size": np.int8, "number": np.int32}
>>> data = pd.read_json(json, orient="index", dtype=dtype)
>>> type(type(data["matrix"][1]))
list
```

For the conversion I was wondering if there is a more subtle (and perhaps more efficient) way than brutal conversion:

```
data["matrix"] = data["matrix"].apply(lambda x: np.array(x, dtype=np.int8))
```

Comment: what is your desired data set?

Comment: Dunno, seems like your only option is `pd.read_json(json, orient="index").applymap(np.array)`

Comment: I highly doubt that a pandas dataframe will provide any sort of performance advantage over plain Python data structures (or your own custom classes). Pandas works well for numeric, panel data. You've left the realm of subtle and efficient pandas when you decided to force a Json blob into an object dtyped dataframe.

Comment: Also, I do not understand why you save the matrix size. Once your matrix object exists, the size is never calculated again, it stored as an attribute.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: The first reason for saving the size was to keep exactly the same information as the original dataset, I just changed the format. The second is that I was padding all matrices such that they all have the same sizes to feed them to a neural network (but now I think this is not the best approach, I should not pad when loading, just when feeding them to the NN).
I would have expected Pandas to be able to manage also matrices, this looks to me a quite fundamental type of objects – but maybe I was too naive.

Comment: @MaxU: My desired dataset would store the "matrix" and (maybe) "vector" column as int arrays, "euler" as integer, and "size" as list (all of the smallest possible int type). It looked to me as being the most efficient memory-wise, but again, I am quite a beginner in the topics of statistical analysis and ML, so I don't have any strong opinion.